# parsing a formdata object with javascript

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data

My company uses a propitiatory application server in which the server side programs are written in javascript (not node.js) . This is a very initial thing and support isn't that good

Now here is my problem :

I am having to process an uploaded csv on the server side .. I am using the super answer at [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery/8758614#8758614) (passing the formdata object with jquery) and i am able to access the sent file on the server side . But how do i parse it out ?

It looks like this

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryU5rJUDxGnj15hIGW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="test.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

------WebKitFormBoundaryU5rJUDxGnj15hIGW--
```

I'm really confused how to handle this file with plain javascript on the server side.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so , i managed to do this myself. I tested it out of a couple of browsers and noticed that the header was 3 lines and the footer was 1 line.

I just wrote one simple parser that splits the file by the newline character and put its into an array line by line.

This helps me in processing till now .

```
function doProcess()
{

var i=0;
var str = '';
var arrayList = [];

for (i=0;i<fileContent.length;i++)
{
    if (fileContent[i] !== '\n')
    {
        str += fileContent[i];
    }
    else
    {
        str = str.replace("\r","");
        if (trim(str) !== "")
        {
            arrayList.push(str);
        }
        str = '';
    }
}

    // Remove header
    arrayList.splice(0,3);

    // Remove footer
    arrayList.splice(arrayList.length-1,1);

    // arrayList is an array of all the lines in the file
    console.log(arrayList); 
}
```

Comment: just want to say i like your approach

Answer (score 13):

Best would be to use [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable), browserify and polyfill it.
Here is a standalone parser, works both with string and raw responses.
Make sure you use a modern browser for the raw-stuff.

```
/* 
 * MultiPart_parse decodes a multipart/form-data encoded response into a named-part-map.
 * The response can be a string or raw bytes.
 *
 * Usage for string response:
 *      var map = MultiPart_parse(xhr.responseText, xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
 *
 * Usage for raw bytes:
 *      xhr.open(..);     
 *      xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";
 *      ...
 *      var map = MultiPart_parse(xhr.response, xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type'));
 *
 * TODO: Can we use https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable
 * See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965107/converting-between-strings-and-arraybuffers
 * See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html
 *
 * Copyright@ 2013-2014 Wolfgang Kuehn, released under the MIT license.
*/
function MultiPart_parse(body, contentType) {
    // Examples for content types:
    //      multipart/form-data; boundary="----7dd322351017c"; ...
    //      multipart/form-data; boundary=----7dd322351017c; ...
    var m = contentType.match(/boundary=(?:"([^"]+)"|([^;]+))/i);

    if ( !m ) {
        throw new Error('Bad content-type header, no multipart boundary');
    }

    var boundary = m[1] || m[2];

    function Header_parse(header) {
        var headerFields = {};
        var matchResult = header.match(/^.*name="([^"]*)"$/);
        if ( matchResult ) headerFields.name = matchResult[1];
        return headerFields;
    }

    function rawStringToBuffer( str ) {
        var idx, len = str.length, arr = new Array( len );
        for ( idx = 0 ; idx < len ; ++idx ) {
            arr[ idx ] = str.charCodeAt(idx) & 0xFF;
        }
        return new Uint8Array( arr ).buffer;
    }

    // \r\n is part of the boundary.
    var boundary = '\r\n--' + boundary;

    var isRaw = typeof(body) !== 'string';

    if ( isRaw ) {
        var view = new Uint8Array( body );
        s = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, view);
    } else {
        s = body;
    }

    // Prepend what has been stripped by the body parsing mechanism.
    s = '\r\n' + s;

    var parts = s.split(new RegExp(boundary)),
        partsByName = {};

    // First part is a preamble, last part is closing '--'
    for (var i=1; i<parts.length-1; i++) {
      var subparts = parts[i].split('\r\n\r\n');
      var headers = subparts[0].split('\r\n');
      for (var j=1; j<headers.length; j++) {
        var headerFields = Header_parse(headers[j]);
        if ( headerFields.name ) {
            fieldName = headerFields.name;
        }
      }

      partsByName[fieldName] = isRaw?rawStringToBuffer(subparts[1]):subparts[1];
    }

    return partsByName;
}
```

Comment: very useful. but has a bug. if the content of a part contains "\r\n\r\n" then it would be splittet too and the content is not the original value, but just the first part of the content, until "\r\n\r\n"
`var contentStartPos = parts[i].indexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 4;
    var partHeaders = parts[i].substr(0, contentStartPos - 4).split("\r\n");
    var partContent = parts[i].substr(contentStartPos);`

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can use the built-in [Response.formData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/formData) method:

```js
const multipartPayload =
`------WebKitFormBoundaryU5rJUDxGnj15hIGW\r
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileToUpload"; filename="test.csv"\r
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel\r
\r
1
2
3
4
5
...
\r
------WebKitFormBoundaryU5rJUDxGnj15hIGW--`

const boundary = multipartPayload.slice(2, multipartPayload.indexOf('\r\n'))
new Response(multipartPayload, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${boundary}`
  }
})
  .formData()
  .then(formData => {
    // The parsed data
    console.log([...formData.entries()])
    
    // In this particular example fileToUpload is a file,
    // so you need to call one more method to read its context
    formData.get('fileToUpload')
      .text()
      .then(text => console.log(text))
  })
```

The `\r` in the multipart payload are necessary, because line breaks **must** be `\r\n`, except the sub-payloads themselves. If you have a properly formed `multipart/form-data` payload, you don't need to add `\r`.

If you want to parse an HTTP response, you can use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) response directly:

```js
fetch('/formdata-response')
  .then(response => response.formData())
  .then(formData => console.log([...formData.entries()]))
```