# How to properly upload and save photo using Node.JS (no frameworks)

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post, image-uploading

I'm adding photo uploading feature to my chat. I have POST parser from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21634944/9255534), and little code that saves image to uploads directory.

```
var ext = exports.getFileExt(Object.keys(partsByName)[0]);
var time = (new Date()).getTime();
fs.writeFile("./img/user/upload_" + time + "." + ext,
    partsByName[Object.keys(partsByName)[0]], "binary", function (err) {
        if (!err) {
            res.writeHead(200, "OK", { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
            res.write(exports.wrapHTML(<title>, <html>, <font params>));
            res.end();
        } else {
            console.error(err);
            res.writeHead(500, "Internal Server Error");
            res.end();
        }
    });
```

Image saves with expected name, but it doesn't opens and I think there is incorrect encoding.

Source file start looks like this:

`яШяа JFIF  H H  яб"Exif  MM *`

but newly saved file is different:

`ээээ JFIF  H H  ээ"Exif  MM *`

I tried writing my own parser before I found that answer, and it has other structure - it extracted boundary with `/boundary=(.+)/` regex, then getting file extension from parsed file name, and cutting 2 first lines with array, then joining with "\r\n", and applying `substr(boundary.length, data.length - (boundary.length * 2))` (and some other corrections), saving with `fs.writeFile`, and file again looked incorrectly.

UPD: Now I think that Cyrillic just lost when sending data. In console and browser they look as unknown character (stroked rectangle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body parser is probably not correct. Handling `multipart/form` POST data in a safe way can be rather tricky.

When you want to get a better grasp of how it works it's great to write your own version. As soon as you have a good enough understanding you should switch to battletested code from a library.

About the first bytes, they are sometimes called 'magic bytes', read more about those here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

These bytes are used by most operating systems to determine the type of file.

Comment: I tried writing my own parser before I found that answer, and it has other structure - extracted boundary with `/boundary=(.+)/` regex, then getting file extension from parsed file name, and cutting 2 first lines with array, then joining with "\r\n", and applying `substr(boundary.length, data.length - (boundary.length * 2))` (and some other corrections), saving with `fs.writeFile`, and file again looked incorrectly.

Comment: You should not read the body of the request as a string but as bytes. A file contains bytes that will interpreted differently when you 'convert' it to a string. Just read the bytes and handle them according to the [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046). Again - if you want to use this in production, use a library.